# Can't uninstall apps from homescreen Android 8.0 after settings sync

Tags: samsung, 8.0-oreo

I recently bought a Galaxy S9+ This would allow me to uninstall apps from the homescreen. If I did a press and hold on the app an uninstall option would pop up on the menu.

I just did a data sync which syncs settings from my old galaxy s7 edge running android 7. Now when I press and hold on an app in the homescreen a message comes up that says "Remove from Home" instead of uninstall.

How do I get the uninstall option back? I can't find anything in the settings that would change this.

Comment: Are you in Easy Mode? Standard Mode as [documented](https://www.verizonwireless.com/support/knowledge-base-216741/) should allow uninstall like this. Check your Mode setting from: `Settings > Display > Easy / Standard mode`. Usually the manuals reveal the important things.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. The old migrated app shortcuts have this issue. When I deleted the old shortcuts and simply remade the shortcuts again the uninstall option returned